# Distorted H3 hexagons - even though projection is matching

Tags: coordinate-system, distortion, h3

Using H3-py's `h3_to_geo_boundary` a WKT linestring (via shapley polygons) can be generated.

When later visualizing the hexagons, why are they distorted? How can this be fixed?

[image]

To my best knowledge, H3 works in EPSG:4326.
As you can see on the plot, the base-map coordinate system is also set to 4326. And QGIS also interprets the CSV of WKT strings as 4326.

Why do I see the distortion? How can it be fixed?

Comment: what projection did the hexagons come with or what did you set the projection of the hexagons to?

Comment: I kept the default output of H3. When loading it from QGIS it was interpreted as 4326.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of EPSG:4326 is simply just a representation of the WGS84 coordinate system which is a 1:1 mapping from the spheroid to an XY plane.
And, while WGS84 is the correct spheroid for h3 geometries, you need a conformal map projection if you want to preserve the hexagon shapes.

Shown below is a reference image taken from QGIS using EPSG:3857.

[image]